# TLS Secure communication - Certificate validation

Tags: ssl, certificate, x509, ca

I need some information for validating a server certificate.
Am looking to perform date based validation as the first step.
To be precise, am looking at the possibility of expiry of a server certificate that is signed by a CA.
If the CA validity expires on December 2022, can I still get it to sign my server certificate that is supposed to expire only in April 2023?
In other words, if my server certificate has a certain expiry date, can I assume that the CA that signed it also has validity equal to or greater than the server certificate?
If not, should I do a separate date validation for the CA or chain of CAs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/997788/can-a-server-certificate-expire-after-its-issuer and (as linked there) https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/120469/can-a-ssl-certificate-have-longer-validity-period-than-its-parent-in-x.509-chain

Answer (score 1):

> If the CA validity expires on December 2022, can I still get it to sign my server certificate that is supposed to expire only in April 2023?

technically, yes. However most CA implementations restrict issued certificates validity to intersect the CA certificate lifetime.

> If not, should I do a separate date validation for the CA or chain of CAs?

as a good practice, you should validate all certificates in the chain. However, I would recommend to NOT write your own validation. Most frameworks provide fully-featured certificate validation engines. Date validation is not the only thing that requires validation, there are many other checks to perform as specified in [RFC 5280 §6](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5280#section-6). Use framework-provided APIs to validate the certificate and rely on their results.

Comment: Thanks Vadims. I am using openssl, do you think using X509_verify_cert() will be sufficient?

Comment: yes, this will do exactly what you want.